# how to add and delete favorites in asp.net core api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I develop a news application with ASP.net API. I want users to be able to add and deleted their favorites articles. I created a Favorites model like this:

```cs
public class Favorites{

   public String userId {get; set;}
   public UserEntity User {get; set;}
   public int articleId {get; set; }
   public virtual Article article {get; set;}

}
```

I initialized it with dotnet fluentapi:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Favorites>().HasKey(a => new{ a.articleId, a.userId });
```

this is how the controller looks like :

```cs
 public class FavoritesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

        public FavoritesController(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

            _context.Database.EnsureCreated(); 
        }

        // GET: api/Favorites
        [HttpGet(Name = nameof(GetAllFavorites))]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<FavoriteDTo>>> GetAllFavorites( [FromQuery] NewRoomQueryParameters queryParameter)
        {
            IQueryable<Favorites> favs = _context.Favorites;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryParameter.sortBy))
            {
                if (typeof(Favorites).GetProperty(queryParameter.sortBy) != null)
                {
                    favs = favs.OrderByCustom(queryParameter.sortBy, queryParameter.SortOrder);
                }
            }

           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryParameter.userId))
            {
                favs = favs.Where(p => p.userId == queryParameter.userId);
            }

            return await favs.Include(a => a.Article)
                               .ThenInclude(a => a.Author)
                              .Include(a => a.Article)
                                .ThenInclude(a => a.Comments)
                             .Select(x => favoriteToDTo(x)).ToListAsync(); 
        }

        // GET: api/Favorites/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<FavoriteDTo>> GetFavorites(int id)
        {
            IQueryable<Favorites> favs = _context.Favorites; 

            var favorites = await favs.Include(x => x.Article).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.articleId == id ) ;

            if (favorites == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return favoriteToDTo(favorites);
        }

   
        // POST: api/Favorites
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<FavoriteDTo>> PostFavorites(FavoriteDTo favDTo)
        {
            var fav = new Favorites
            {
                articleId = favDTo.articleId, 
                userId = favDTo.userId
            }; 

            _context.Favorites.Add(fav);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (FavoritesExists(fav.articleId))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetFavorites), new { id = fav.articleId }, fav);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Favorites/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteFavorites(int id)
        {
            var favorites = await _context.Favorites.FindAsync(id);
            if (favorites == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Favorites.Remove(favorites);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private static FavoriteDTo favoriteToDTo(Favorites favorites) => new FavoriteDTo
        {
            articleId = favorites.articleId,
            Article = favorites.Article,
            User = favorites.User,
            userId = favorites.userId
        }; 

        private bool FavoritesExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Favorites.Any(e => e.articleId == id);
        }
    }
```

I can add Favorites just fine. But I cannot remove them. Can somebody help me out ? if it is not the good
way to implement this functionality , please I would like to learn how to do it the right way.

Comment: What does `id` represent in `DeleteFavorites(int id)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on How you want to delete the favorite. If you want to delete the Article from Favorite for a user,

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteFavoritesForUser(int Articleid, string userId)
    {
        var favorites = await _context.Favorites.FindBy(x=>x.UserId ==userId && x=>x.ArticleId ==Articleid);
        if (favorites == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Favorites.RemoveRange(favorites);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  _context.Favorites.Remove(favorites);
```

with

```
  _context.Favorites.RemoveRange(favorites);
```